# Line on the same height on CV with multicols

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol, resume, cv

I am trying to wrap up my CV but the problem I am facing is with two lines not being on the same level.

[image: Lines are not on the same height]

My code is below:

```
\begin{multicols}{2}{}
\begin{rSection}{|Computer Skills|}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Python (numpy, scipy, Keras, TensorFlow, scikit-learn), C++, MATLAB, Bash/Shell, Git 
    \item Databases: MySQL, SQL Server
    \item AWS S3, EC2
\end{itemize}
\end{rSection}
\columnbreak
\begin{rSection}{Awards}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{NSERC Engage Grant}, Awarded to researches in collaboration with industry partners,  November 2018
    \item \textbf{Agilent Capstone Design Award}, Undergraduate Capstone Design Conference, March 2014
```

`rSection` comes from the following code:

```
% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}
```

The beginning of my file is:

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style 

\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.3 in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.3in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Could you please turn your code into a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the issue you describe (Where/How is the `rSecrion` environment defined?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your used class `resume.cls` is very old and it would be better to not use it ...

However, in your case the culprit is your used environment `multicols`. In the documentation of this package (type `texdoc multicols` on you terminal/console) is mentioned, that the columns are typed balanced, that means the columns start at the same place and the last line of both columns is placed on the same height. That can only be done with different white space between the lines in both columns.

That is the reason why you get the output you showed us in your question.

Now you can use -- for example, see documentation please! -- the command `\raggedcolumns` to omit the balanced output of columns.

Please see the following mwe

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.3 in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.3in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}

\name{John Doe } % Your name

%\address{The address} % Your address

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}{}
\raggedcolumns % <======================================================
\begin{rSection}{Computer Skills}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Python (numpy, scipy, Keras, TensorFlow, scikit-learn), C++, MATLAB, Bash/Shell, Git 
    \item Databases: MySQL, SQL Server
    \item AWS S3, EC2
\end{itemize}
\end{rSection}

%\begin{rSection}{Computer Skills}
%\begin{itemize}
    %\item Python (numpy, scipy, Keras, TensorFlow, scikit-learn), C++, MATLAB, Bash/Shell, Git 
    %\item Databases: MySQL, SQL Server
    %\item AWS S3, EC2
    %\item test
    %\item test2
%\end{itemize}
%\end{rSection}
\columnbreak
\begin{rSection}{Awards}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{NSERC Engage Grant}, Awarded to researches in collaboration with industry partners,  November 2018
    \item \textbf{Agilent Capstone Design Award}, Undergraduate Capstone Design Conference, March 2014
\end{itemize}
\end{rSection}

\begin{rSection}{Awards}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{NSERC Engage Grant}, Awarded to researches in collaboration with industry partners,  November 2018
    \item \textbf{Agilent Capstone Design Award}, Undergraduate Capstone Design Conference, March 2014
\end{itemize}
\end{rSection}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting pdf]

If you do not want the unbalanced output you have to change your code to get balancable text in both columns.

For example you can try the following code

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.4 in,top=0.3 in,right=0.4 in,bottom=0.3in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand{\tab}[1]{\hspace{.2667\textwidth}\rlap{#1}}
\newcommand{\itab}[1]{\hspace{0em}\rlap{#1}}

\name{John Doe } % Your name

%\address{The address} % Your address

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}{}
%\raggedcolumns % <======================================================
\begin{rSection}{Computer Skills}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Python (numpy, scipy, Keras, TensorFlow, scikit-learn), C++, MATLAB, Bash/Shell, Git 
    \item Databases: MySQL, SQL Server
    \item AWS S3, EC2
\end{itemize}
\end{rSection}

\begin{rSection}{Computer Skills} % <===================================
\begin{itemize}
    \item Python (numpy, scipy, Keras, TensorFlow, scikit-learn), C++, MATLAB, Bash/Shell, Git 
    \item Databases: MySQL, SQL Server
    \item AWS S3, EC2
    \item test % <======================================================
    \item test2 % <=====================================================
\end{itemize}
\end{rSection}
\columnbreak
\begin{rSection}{Awards}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{NSERC Engage Grant}, Awarded to researches in collaboration with industry partners,  November 2018
    \item \textbf{Agilent Capstone Design Award}, Undergraduate Capstone Design Conference, March 2014
\end{itemize}
\end{rSection}

\begin{rSection}{Awards}
\begin{itemize}
    \item \textbf{NSERC Engage Grant}, Awarded to researches in collaboration with industry partners,  November 2018
    \item \textbf{Agilent Capstone Design Award}, Undergraduate Capstone Design Conference, March 2014
\end{itemize}
\end{rSection}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

with its result:

[image: balanced columns]

The used class file for this mwe is:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Medium Length Professional CV - RESUME CLASS FILE
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% This class file defines the structure and design of the template. 
%
% Original header:
% Copyright (C) 2010 by Trey Hunner
%
% Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification,
% are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
% notice and this notice are preserved. This file is offered as-is,
% without any warranty.
%
% Created by Trey Hunner and modified by www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ProvidesClass{resume}[2010/07/10 v0.9 Resume class]

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   HEADINGS COMMANDS: Commands for printing name and address
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\def \name#1{\def\@name{#1}} % Defines the \name command to set name
\def \@name {} % Sets \@name to empty by default

\def \addressSep {$\diamond$} % Set default address separator to a diamond

% One, two or three address lines can be specified 
\let \@addressone \relax
\let \@addresstwo \relax
\let \@addressthree \relax

% \address command can be used to set the first, second, and third address (last 2 optional)
\def \address #1{
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{
    \def \@addresstwo {#1}
  }{
  \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{
  \def \@addressthree {#1}
  }{
     \def \@addressone {#1}
  }}
}

% \printaddress is used to style an address line (given as input)
\def \printaddress #1{
  \begingroup
    \def \\ {\addressSep\ }
    \centerline{#1}
  \endgroup
  \par
  \addressskip
}

% \printname is used to print the name as a page header
\def \printname {
  \begingroup
    \hfil{\MakeUppercase{\namesize\bf \@name}}\hfil
    \nameskip\break
  \endgroup
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PRINT THE HEADING LINES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\let\ori@document=\document
\renewcommand{\document}{
  \ori@document  % Begin document
  \printname % Print the name specified with \name
  \@ifundefined{@addressone}{}{ % Print the first address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addressone}}
  \@ifundefined{@addresstwo}{}{ % Print the second address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addresstwo}}
     \@ifundefined{@addressthree}{}{ % Print the third address if specified
    \printaddress{\@addressthree}}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   SECTION FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   WORK EXPERIENCE FORMATTING
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\newenvironment{rSubsection}[4]{ % 4 input arguments - company name, year(s) employed, job title and location
 {\bf #1} \hfill {#2} % Bold company name and date on the right
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}{}{ % If the third argument is not specified, don't print the job title and location line
  \\
  {\em #3} \hfill {\em #4} % Italic job title and location
  }\smallskip
  \begin{list}{$\cdot$}{\leftmargin=0em} % \cdot used for bullets, no indentation
   \itemsep -0.5em \vspace{-0.5em} % Compress items in list together for aesthetics
  }{
  \end{list}
  \vspace{0.5em} % Some space after the list of bullet points
}

% The below commands define the whitespace after certain things in the document - they can be \smallskip, \medskip or \bigskip
\def\namesize{\huge} % Size of the name at the top of the document
\def\addressskip{\smallskip} % The space between the two address (or phone/email) lines
\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip} % The space above the horizontal line for each section 
\def\nameskip{\bigskip} % The space after your name at the top
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section
```